# rename files with python - regex

Tags: python, regex, file, rename

I am wanting to rename 1k files using python. they are all in the format somejunkDATE.doc

basically, I would like to delete all the junk, and only leave the date. I am unsure how to match this for all files in a directory.

thanks

Comment: We can't help if we know nothing about how `DATE` is formatted.

Comment: Is the junk always the same, or is it different for each file? Also, what format is the date in?

Comment: the 'junk' also contains every type of character, symbol, etc, random lengths, rather lengthy

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If your date format is the same throughout, just use slicing

```
>>> file="someJunk20101022.doc"
>>> file[-12:]
'20101022.doc'
>>> import os
>>> os.rename(file, file[-12:]
```

If you want to check if the numbers are valid dates, pass `file[-12:-3]` to `time` or `datetime` module to check.

Say your files are all in a directory (no sub directories)

```
import os
import glob
import datetime,time #as required
os.chdir("/mypath")
for files in glob.glob("*.doc"):
    newfilename = files[-12:]
    # here to check date if desired
    try:
       os.rename(files,newfilename)
    except OSError,e:
       print e
    else: print "ok"
```